# Python 3 taking multiple data types in input, separated by space

Tags: python, input, types

So i need to find a way to take multiple data types as an input and store them in variables. Lets say i have 3 variables, each of them should store a fixed data type
a - float
b - str
c - int

and if the user enters a wrong, he will be asked to type again.
The user will enter all of them, separated by space but i can't think of a way to store them in the variables, while keeping the data type. I've tried with .split(), but it just transforms them into strings. It's probably something quite obvious, but can't figure it out right now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _t's probably something quite obvious, but can't figure it out right now_. Probably yeah, what have you tried ?

Comment: you need to cast each of them

Comment: Please include your attempt in the question. `split` doesn't _transform_ them into strings, all `input` values are string, `split()` just chops the string up into other strings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
def myfucn(vars):
    vars = vars.split()
    try:
        float(vars[0])
        if not "." in vars[0]:
            raise Exception("First var should be INT not Float")
    except ValueError:
        print("Error not Float found")

    try:
        int(vars[2])
    except ValueError:
        print("Error Int no found")

    #answer
    a_float, b_str, c_int = vars
    print(" Yes ")
```

greetings

Comment: `if not "." in vars[0]:` why? `float(vars[0])` would already have failed.

Comment: 'cause `float("45")` ,  return `45.0` , and 45  -> int

Comment: Fair enough, I mis-remembered the question distinguishing between float and int and couldn't understand the exception messages until you edited them into English.

Comment: @Edwin Cubillos Thanks to u as well for the fast answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track if the split() function. The problem is that when you say that user will give three values separated by ' ', you are taking in a string.
The following is a string:
'34.44 35.45 5'
Maybe what you can do is after using split, you can cast each returned item to a variable. If you still need to check the type of variable, you can use the type() function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but this is a bit like a trailer to a movie. Unless the OP shows their code and you can adapt this answer, it doesn't explain much.

Comment: The thing is, i did the following - using .split(), afterwards i changed each type of the variables to the desired ones. It works for a while, but lets say the user has entered a value, which does not correspond to the desired one: If variable a is a float, the user enters for example a string 'w', i can't convert it to float. Thats the main issue, which i can't solve.

Comment: @zauahiri in which case you need to use [`try`/`except`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)